# Extra query sent in socket Progrmming

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I am trying to implement a basic server-client socket program, where the server sends few messages and the client responds to those messages. The messages here are stored in the form of buffers.The following is a high-level interpretation of logic :

Server-----------------------------Client

FF,FD,18 --->

```
                 <---FF,FE,18
```

FF,FD,1E --->

```
                 <---FF,FE,1E
```

Client-Side

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <arpa/telnet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server1;

   char buffer1[256];

   if (argc < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
        return(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    /* Create a socket point */

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (sockfd < 0) 
    {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        return(1);
    }

    server1 = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server1 == NULL)
    {
     fprintf(stderr,"ERROR no such host \n");
     exit(0);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr , sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server1->h_addr, (char*)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server1->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons( portno );


/*Connect to server*/
 if (connect( sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr) ) < 0) 
    {
         perror("ERROR connecting");
         return(1);
    }   
 int l = 1 ;


    bzero(buffer1,256);
int j=1;
int i =0;

while(j <= 4)
{

        n= recv(sockfd,buffer1,3,0);
        if(n<0)
           printf("ERROR reading in socket %d  len %d", n, sizeof(buffer1));


          {          
           printf("Recieving Buffer %d from Server side %hhX %hhX %hhX \n",n, buffer1[0], buffer1[1], buffer1[2]); 
           buffer1[1] = 0xfc;
           n= send(sockfd,buffer1,3,0);
       if(n<0)
           printf("ERROR writing in socket %d  \n", n);        
           printf("Sent Buffer bytes %d: %hhX %hhX %hhX from client side \n\n",n,buffer1[0],buffer1[1],buffer1[2]);
           j++;
           l++;
          }

}
return(0);
}
```

Server-Side :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <arpa/telnet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char buff1[][3]= {{0xff , 0xfd, 0x18},{0xff , 0xfd, 0x1e},{0xff , 0xfd, 0x1d},{0xff , 0xfd , 0x18}};

char recbuf[1024];

int main(int argc , char *argv[] )
{
  int sockfd , newsockfd , portno;
  socklen_t clilen;
  char buffer[256];
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
  int n;

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
  if (sockfd < 0 )
  {
   perror("Error opening socket ");
   exit(1);
  }

  /* Initialize socket structure */
  bzero((char *) &serv_addr , sizeof(serv_addr));
  portno = atoi(argv[1]);
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY ; 
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

 /* Now bind the host address using client */
  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr , sizeof(serv_addr)) <0)

  { 
   perror("Error on binding");
   exit(1);
  } 
    if(listen(sockfd,5)<0)
     {
       perror("Error on listen");
       exit(1);
     }
        int k = 1;
       int count = 0;
        clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    if (newsockfd < 0)
    {
     perror("ERROR on accept");
     exit(1);
    }
         int ctr = sizeof(buff1) ; 

     printf("Server Sending (DO TERMINAL TYPE)\n");
         while(k < ctr)
         {// int i = 0;

         while ((n = send(newsockfd,&buff1[count][0],3,0))> 0)
         { 
                  if(n < 0)
               {
                    close(newsockfd);
                    exit(1);
                   }
                  else if (n > 0)
                  {
           printf("Server Sent query %d to Client:%hhX %hhX %hhX\n", count , buff1[count][0], buff1[count][1], buff1[count][2]);
           n = recv(newsockfd, recbuf , sizeof(recbuf),0);
                   printf("n = %d\n",n);
                   printf("Server received response from Client: %hhX %hhX %hhX\n\n", recbuf[0], recbuf[1], recbuf[2]);

                  }
        }

          k++;
         }


      close(sockfd);
      return(0);


}
```

For every message sent from server there should be a response from client but in my code , there is always an extra message from server sent to the client.As the output shows there is an extra query sent at server side.

The buffer at the server side has 4 queries. So basically it should send 4 queries but here it is sending one extra query.

output :
Server side :

```
debian:~/sam$ ./single_sample 67777
Server Sending (DO TERMINAL TYPE)
Server Sent query 0 to Client:FF FD 18
n = 3
Server received response from Client: FF FC 18

Server Sent query 1 to Client:FF FD 1E
n = 3
Server received response from Client: FF FC 1E

Server Sent query 2 to Client:FF FD 1D
n = 3
Server received response from Client: FF FC 1D

Server Sent query 3 to Client:FF FD 18
n = 3
Server received response from Client: FF FC 18

Server Sent query 0 to Client:FF FD 18
n = -1
Server received response from Client: FF FC 18
```

Client side :

```
debian:~/sam$ ./single_client 127.0.0.1 67777
Recieving Buffer 3 from Server side FF FD 18 
Sent Buffer bytes 3: FF FC 18 from client side 

Recieving Buffer 3 from Server side FF FD 1E 
Sent Buffer bytes 3: FF FC 1E from client side 

Recieving Buffer 3 from Server side FF FD 1D 
Sent Buffer bytes 3: FF FC 1D from client side 

Recieving Buffer 3 from Server side FF FD 18 
Sent Buffer bytes 3: FF FC 18 from client side
```

How should I solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 int ctr = sizeof(buff1) ;
```

Try:

```
 int ctr = sizeof(buff1) / sizeof(buff1[0]) ;
```

This should give you 'ctr' as the number of elements in 'buff1', where each element is a character array you want to send in one iteration.  Currently you're getting the total number of bytes in that multidimensional array.  I believe you will want to initialize 'k' to 0 as well, instead of 1.

Comment: Why are you doing 'count = count % 4;' if you have 3 sets of characters to send?

Comment: buff1 has 4 queries ..so using count%4 to divide each querie

Comment: OK.  But then you use the % operator to send each query again in the inner loop?  How are you intending to break out of the inner loop, other than on a failed send()?  If you only want to send the 4 queries, once each, is the outer loop even necessary?

Comment: I commented the count section, still it is sending an extra query.